# Second AJAX response rewrite First (JS, JSON)

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I am trying to solve this problem of mine: I am making two ajax calls on window.load, and it seems like second AJAX response rewrite first one before I function can proceed it or I am making something wrong... anyway I am not able to solve it without making calls synchronous and i don't really want to do that for obvious reasons.

So Here is my code (Javascript) To Create new XMLHttpRequest:

```
function createRequest(){
  if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    return new XMLHttpRequest;
  else 
    return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
```

My send request function (to sending them)

```
function sendRequest( url, callback){
  request = createRequest();

  if(typeof callback === 'function'){
    request.onreadystatechange = callback();
  }

  request.open("GET", url, true);
  request.send();
}
```

and finally my callback

```
function handleData(){
  return function(){
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
        serverResponse = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

        switch(Object.keys(serverResponse)[0]){
            case "a": function1(serverResponse.a,"a"); break;
            case "b": function2(serverResponse.b,"b"); break;
        }
    }
}
```

I am creating my calls like this:

```
window.onload = function () {
  sendRequest('url' , handleData);
  sendRequest('url2', handleData);
}
```

NOTICE: As you can see, this is simplified version of my code.
In a switch I am calling function1 and 2 these functions are really handling JSON response from server. I am making calls on two different urls on a same domain with different json response. 
Also when I make only one call it works well(Both of them)... Problem only occurs when I am trying to make 2 in a row - And when i make two calls only second one is processed right. Thats why i am thinking that second overwrite first.

I tried to make two functions to handleData so there was `handleData1()` and `handleData2()` instead of single `handleData()` with switch so i call them like this:

```
window.onload = function () {
  sendRequest('url' , handleData1);
  sendRequest('url2', handleData2);
}
```

but i run into problem where second ajax response(always the second call) but again only second one succeed. And then i put `console.log(request)` in both of em, and i get only JSON for second function trying to be processed with second function.(nothing about first one) Sometimes is second function called more times like 4.

Btw `handleData2` does not depend on data from `handleData1`.

If any more questions please do ask :) Thanks

Comment: `function handleData(request){` expects an argument, but you are not passing anything to it: `callback();`. `request = createRequest();` creates a **global** variable. You don't want that. Always use `var`.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that, solve my problem, that argument was typo... So now i know why my second overwrite first :D i feel stupid really ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
request = createRequest();
```

creates a global variable. Every call to the function will override that variable, which is what you are experiencing.

Create a local variable and pass the value to the callback:

```
var request = createRequest();

if(typeof callback === 'function'){
  request.onreadystatechange = callback(request);
}

// ...

function handleData(request) {
    // ...
}
```